# Preload, Prefetch, or Preconnect for a JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

On my site I have a twitch embed, my site performers very well in page speed scores without this embed, but as soon as I add it, it increases loading time significantly. My site is a single page, static website- nothing particularly fancy.

I currently am preloading my single JS file, as well as my stylesheet.

Which of the above mentioned in the title (fetch, load, or connect), should I be using on the twitch embed JS to improve performance?

Currently I just have it stuck at the bottom of the index.html as follows (along with jQuery, perhaps I should be prefetching that too?)

```
<script src= "https://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

for large libraries like this, which seems to be systemic problem with 3rd parties, I lazy load them once the core UX is interactive.

This is how I load stripe on shopping cart pages:

```
function initStripe() {
    var script = document.createElement( "script" );

    script.src = "https://js.stripe.com/v3/";

    script.onload = stripeLoaded;

    document.body.appendChild( script );

}
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and wrapping the script in:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => { 
Will it only load it once it's in view?

Comment: I only load these heavy dependencies once I know they are needed. Otherwise they severely slow the critical rendering path, which means the user is stuck waiting on all that code to load and get evaluated.
If I can figure out how to replace the fat library I do, often saving MBs of JavaScript being loaded.
You are doing it as soon as the DOMContentLoaded event triggers, which could be well before you need to load the script(s).
For example Stripe loads 750kb of JavaScript to make a single fetch call :( And it loads 6 scripts I think.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defered loading. Put all the script tags in the head using defer loading .For eg.

```
<head>
<!-- other headers -->
<script defer src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src= "https://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js"></script>
</head
```

Refer to this article in google developers [Remove Render-Blocking JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS)

Comment: I don't get any render blocking errors, what benefits would this give to preload for example?

Comment: When you put the scripts at the bottom of the page. The page renderer doesnot know about the script until it reaches the bottom at which stage some miliseconds is lost which could have been used to render the large js files. Using defer script at the top inform the render engine of the script which will start loading the script but not bock the further execution of the html rendering. Preload are usually used with service worker for caching the static file which can be used sometime later in the future. With defer With defer, browser will run your script when the page finished parsing.